# How get the "real" blockhash from Solidity to Web3

Tags: solidity, web3js

I have trying save the transactions of user in contract like:

```
function Donar() external payable{
    require(msg.value >= MINIMUM, "Minium amount is 0.05");
    bool nuevo = false;
    
    blockValue =  uint256(blockhash(block.number-1));//is a uint256
    //añadimos el nuevo mientro
    if(balances[msg.sender]<=0){
        users.push(msg.sender);
        nuevo = true;
    }
    balances[msg.sender] +=msg.value;
    emit Donation(msg.sender, balances[msg.sender], nuevo);
}
```

But when from Web3 js
I trying to acces to Blockvalue this back me a different result that the transaction.

If I do a transaccion "Donar"
I get for example this transaction:
0x5e99f8a0b2397a0d3e6024d42bc66ef7b0db776bdc3e5232ed8cb1dfccbcb28d

But if I check the Blockvalue I get this:
45462209008309196972246523876171350366909309459187506831567695009831863640741

I from JS tryed to encrypt to sha256
but then I got another different result like
1c092b7a0d025a1754c4cf109668ff21a75e3b167f2a99f33747bf7b23b54b7f

How Can I save the transaction Hash in contract?

Answer (score 2):

`blockhash` is not the same as `sha256(blockNumber)`

It's the hash of the whole block (including transactions and metadata), published by the winning miner, and used as one of the inputs for the next block. Hence - **block chain**.

Example of one of the recent blocks: https://etherscan.io/block/13284032

- Block number: `13284032`

  - SHA256 of this number: `0x2ed065813c261f30844cfed7a49ad794b8517a71e9e108ae36b94514d6c978d6`
- Block hash: `0x778959bc43e97a43e525003cf54c07f4a333aceffdd763d9473ce158a2cf3a5a`

---

Hot to get the blockhash using web3 (at least in JS for inspiration; I see your question is tagged `web3-java` but I don't know Java):

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3('<provider URL>');
web3.eth.getBlock(13284032).then((block) => {
    console.log(block.hash);
});
```

Comment: But I want save it from solidity. I know how get the transaction from WEb3 after to the action, but in the same call I wanna save it in the contract >.>

Comment: The problem not is un web3.
Is in solidity.
I want save the transaction in solidity in the same action when do a send.

To avoid use SQL or something to save data in web.

If I use in solidity:

blockValue =  bytes32 (blockhash(block.number-1));

I have a different result that the real transacion hash. >.<

Comment: @DanielRayos Transaction hash is a different thing from the block hash. But  it's currently (v0.8) not available in Solidity.

Comment: OH Then in Solidity are any way to get the transaccion? :S

Comment: @DanielRayos You can only get two of the transaction properties: `gasprice` and `origin`. See the [cheatsheet](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.7/cheatsheet.html#global-variables) for more info.